useParams() returns null
When I try to call the useParams() hook in nextjs, it's null when it should not, according to the documentation.
this is my directory structure:
pages
├── [gameCode]
│   └── index.tsx

inside index.tsx, while visiting http://localhost:3001/ca850a(example game code):

'use client'

import { useParams } from 'next/navigation';

const GameIndex = () => {

   const params = useParams();
   const gameCode = params.gameCode; // error here
   console.log(gameCode);

return(<div></div>)
}


export default GameIndex;

i get an error that params is null.
I tried multiple methods, but no one worked.

I saw a post saying that you should force the page to be dynamic, put this in your index.tsx export const dynamic='force-dynamic'; 

The doc comment on useParams reads "If used from pages/, the hook will return null." So it's typed to return null, and you're code will need to handle the case where it is null.

the docs say you use a prop (typescripts at the bottom):  https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes

hi, thanks for the responses. I passed params as a prop in this manner: const GameIndex = ( { params }: { params: { gameCode: string } } ) => {}. now it retruns undefined instead of null.

If you are using the pages router still you should follow the documentation here for accessing params: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
 
export default function Page() {
  const router = useRouter()
  return <p>Post: {router.query.slug}</p>
}


